# Jquery Syntax highlighter xml not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, syntax-highlighting, code-snippets

I'm using Jquery Syntax highlighter - http://steamdev.com/snippet/ to highlight my code but for some reason the below XML is not being highlited in my web page.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".htmlCode").snippet("xml",{style:"peachpuff"})
})
```

HTML Code

```
 <pre class="htmlCode">
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

The code is displayed but without the tags -

```
com.sun.jersey
        jersey-server
        1.8
```

Comment: Looks like you need to escape the &lt;s and &gt;s.

Comment: I have very big list of xml code that needs to be included, wondering if I have to include &lt for each and every tag..

Comment: I'm afraid so: the <![CDATA[ construct doesn't seem to be accepted.